# Is it possible to create a String extension `isEmptyOrNull` in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods, nullability

First off let's define some criteria for this extension:

1. It should return true if the object is null or an empty string.
2. I should be able to use it on a chained nullable object.
3. I should not have to use parentheses, type casts or `== true` when using the extension.

Here is an example that should work:

```
extension StringExtension on String? {
  bool get isEmptyOrNull {
  // Implementation
  }
}

class MyObject {
  MyObject({this.myString});

  final String? str;
}


// somewhere in the code: 

final MyObject? obj = null;
if(obj?.str.isEmptyOrNull){
  print('object was empty string or had the value null');
}
```

If this code compiles, follows all the criteria, and writes the correct output I would consider the solution correct.

Comment: Your extension would have to be on `Object?` (essentially *everything*) to include being available on `null`, which is the singleton instance of the `Null` class.

Comment: Your question is not correct. `A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition.` Those programmers who tried to answer it are not experienced programmers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write code according to all the criteria and it turned out like this

```
extension StringExtension on String? {
  bool get isNull => this == null;

  bool get isEmptyOrNull => isNull || this!.isEmpty;
}

class MyObject {
  MyObject({this.str});

  final String? str;
}

// somewhere in the code:

void main() {
  const MyObject? objNull = null;
  final MyObject objStrNull = MyObject();
  final MyObject objStrEmpty = MyObject(str: '');
  final MyObject objStrNotEmpty = MyObject(str: 'str');

  print(objNull?.str.isEmptyOrNull); // null
  print((objNull?.str).isEmptyOrNull); // true
  print(objStrNull.str.isEmptyOrNull); // true
  print(objStrEmpty.str.isEmptyOrNull); // true
  print(objStrNotEmpty.str.isEmptyOrNull); // false
}
```

But without parentheses with a null object it produces null and not boolean

Comment: Yes, this was my approach as well, but as you say it does not work in the first case. 
We are also using very good lint 5.1.0 in all our projects, and it will mark parenthesis as a linting error, saying that it's not unnecessary. And since my vs code is set up to run dart fix on save it will automatically remove the `()`, resulting in an error. 
And if I turn off the fixes my code won't pass the pipeline which checks for linting errors, so I can't use it.  
But it was a good atempt and I will give you a upvote for trying :+1:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create a String extension isEmptyOrNull in Dart.

```
extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool get isNullOrEmpty => this == null || isEmpty;
}
```

To use the extension, you can simply call the isNullOrEmpty method on any string variable. For example:

```
String myString = '';

if (myString.isNullOrEmpty) {
  // The string is null or empty
} else {
  // The string is not null or empty
}
```

Comment: It is true that this will work if you have a String?, but in my example above I have a nullable object holding a String, and since the first object will evaluate to null, the function will not be called and the expression will be null instead of a Boolean.
Your extension should also extent String? for this to work.
Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach?

```
extension StringExtension on String? {
   bool get isEmptyOrNull => this?.isEmpty ?? true;
}

class MyObject {
   MyObject({this.myString});

   final String? str;
}

// somewhere in the code:

final MyObject? obj = null;
if (obj?.str.isEmptyOrNull) {
   print('Object was empty string or had the value null');
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work either since the issue is that `obj?` evaluates to null, and therefore the isEmptyOrNull will not be called and the entire expression `obj?.str.isEmptyOrNull` will simply evaluate to null. 
But it's a good idea and one of the things ChatGPT recommended as well when I asked it.

Answer (score 1):

The operatot `?.` is a conditional member access operator.

A conditional member access operator applies a member access (`?.`) operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns `null`. That is:

If `a` evaluates to null, the result of `a?.x` is `null`.

If `a` evaluates to non-null, the result of `a?.x` is the same as the result of `a.x`.

**This way your code will never be able to compile.**

```dart
final MyObject? obj = null;
if(obj?.str.isEmptyOrNull){
  print('object was empty string or had the value null');
}
```